# How to highlight selected text in web view in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Below java script code is working in normal `html`, while using below script in `android`, it is not working.

**Code**

```
function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
            // Non-IE case
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        document.designMode = "on";
        if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
            // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
        if ( !document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour) ) {
            document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            // IE case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}
```

Please someone suggest me how to highlight selected text in `webview`.

Comment: please suggest someone?

Comment: added help at the end

Answer (score 0):

Just a first check: Have you enabled Javascript?
`this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); has already included in activity...